# Is Reverse Flash from a different timeline than Rip Hunter?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, legends-of-tomorrow

In *Flash* (2014), we're introduced to Eobard Thawne, the Reverse Flash, who was born in 2151.  In *Legends of Tomorrow*, we're introduced to Rip Hunter, in the year 2166.  Logically, Eobard would be aware of the events of 2166.  Yet, from what little we hear Eobard say about his past in the 2100s, it seems decidedly different from the 2166 we see Rip come from.

In Rip's time, Vandal Savage has taken over the world, which is then in a brutal dystopia.  Eobard mentions reading up on the events of the present day in history books, and being a distinguished member of his family.  No mention of struggling to survive a brutal world or the global conflict that preceded Savage conquering the world.

Admittedly, both have their own Gideons, which suggests they're both from the same timeline.  But it's not concrete that this means they're from the same timeline, given that Gideon probably originates in the more immediate future.

Do Rip Hunter and Eobard Thawne originate in the same timeline?

Comment: maybe rip hunter comes from the timeline where eobard thawne ceased to exist?

Comment: the fact that they have this whole time organization, while the world burnt to the ground, boggles my mind.

Comment: @Himarm: Rip Hunter mentions something like a 'no intervention policy'

Comment: @Keen: note that Eobard Thawne mentions Rip Hunter in the Season 1 Finale episode as the designer of the Time Sphere.

Answer (score 3):

This can be explained by none other than Harrison Wells.

In the eleventh episode of the second season of The Flash, he explains that while the future has been altered, the much later future still has to happen for events to transpire as they did in the past.

(so basicly "stuff has to happen so whatever has happened can still have happened).

The Reverse Flash is from the future where the world was saved by heroes who have been recruited by Rip Hunter. For the heroes to exist as they do, The Reverse Flash must have come from the future to mold events in the past.

So, in a way, the future being saved by the Heroes of Tomorrow could only exist because they saved the future and allowed The Reverse Flash to exist as he does.

Answer (score 1):

In the Season One finale of the Flash, Eobard Thawne comments on the design of the pod designed to send him through the breach. He says ...

> *'Rip Hunter would be impressed'*

...referring to the pod.

This could support the theory that they are indeed from the same timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in thawne's timeline travel in time is not controled    It's because Thawne threatened Barry's life and so Flash'life that masters of time has been created savage domination of the world is a side effect of erasing-thawne

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SciFi.SE! Do you have any element from the shows to support your theory? Here, we look for detailed and argumented answers rather than opinions.

Answer (score 0):

In the timeline before ReverseFlash killed barry's mum, Vandal Savage never took over the world. Then, RF was born in the year 2151 where the world was fine and Savage had been defeated(probably by the flash and green arrow in the 2020s). RF went back in time and killed barry's mum, and completely changed the timeline. This lead to the  alternate future where vandal takes over and Rip Hunter decides to come back in time to stop him. Rip and RF are from different timelines.